# $scope.passengerNo returns undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm having problems with receiving the value from an angular expression. 
What should happen is when the endOfPageButton is clicked it should pass through the passengerNo and the title. The title is being passed through fine however the passengerNo is always undefined.

Can you tell me how I can get this to update as the passengerNo should be controlled by a textfield and I though the updated value should be automatically injected?

Thanks!

```
    //mainquote.html
    <ion-view view-title="{{title}}" can-swipe-back="true">
      <ion-content ng-controller="QuoteItemCtrl">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="item centerText" style="background-color: brown;">
            <h6 class="headerTextPadding">REGION</h6>
            <h2>{{title}}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="padding40Top padding20Bottom">
          <h2 class="centerText">Select number of Passengers</h2>
          <input ng-model="passengerNo" class="col col-50 col-offset-25 quoteTField" type="textfield">
          <h6 class="centerText">PASSENGERS</h6>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h6 class="logText centerText">SCHOOLS > {{title}} > {{getCost()}} > @ {{multiplier}}</h6>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
      <div class="endOfPageButton">
        <a href="#/app/home/finalquote">
          <button class="button button-full button-clear" ng-click="sendQuoteInfo()">Submit Quote</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </ion-view>


    //controller.js
    app.controller('QuoteItemCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, MakeSchoolQuote, DataThrow) {
      var item = DataThrow.getDataObject();
      $scope.passengerNo = 49;

      $scope.title = item;
      $scope.multiplier = MakeSchoolQuote.getMultipler(item);

      $scope.getCost = function() {
        $scope.pax = $scope.passengerNo;
        var cost = $scope.multiplier * $scope.passengerNo
        console.log("passenger numbers are" + $scope.pax);
        return cost;
      }

      $scope.sendQuoteInfo = function() {
        var data = [$scope.title, $scope.passengerNo, "N/A"];
        var sendData = DataThrow.storeDataObject(data);
      }
    })
```

Comment: 1. Please provide a working example. 2. Why do you pass the values as parameters in `ng-click` when they're already bound to the scope model in the `input`?

Comment: Are you *hooking* up the controller to the view?

Comment: Is your input field wrapped by anything creating an isolated scope (e.g. ngIf, ngRepeat, ...)? This would result in adding the passengerNo to the isolated scope not to the scope which is used for your controller. Easiest way to solve this: add a `$scope.passengerNo = 49` to your controller.

Comment: Also, that's not the way `ngInit` is supposed to be used, please see the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). Initialize the value in the controller instead.

Comment: I've updated to show fuller code for the HTML and reflect @Numyx comment in regards to initialising in controller. However the passengerNo is not updating in the controller for the $scope.sendQuoteInfo() when the textfield is changed. If anyone can spot the problem that would be great thanks!